# Auto-indentation in C#

Tags: html, markup

Is there an open-source library or code-sample in C#, that will re-indent a string of HTML code?

For example, convert this:

```
 <li>
     <a href="#">this</a>



 </li><li><a href="#">that</a>

          </li>
```

To this:

```
 <li>
     <a href="#">this</a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href="#">that</a>
 </li>
```

Note: I don't want any of the HTML to be altered or moved around the way HTML Tidy does.

I *only* want the markup to be re-indented, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/release/5.8.6) if you paste your sample in and choose Language | Html and then Text FX | Text FX Html Tidy | Tidy Reindent Xml ...

Your sample becomes:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">this</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">that</a>
</li>
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. 1) This command uses the 'HTML tidy' component which, when you have a larger amount of HTML, does a lot of other unpleasant things like changing tags. 2) I need a solution that can be coded in C#.

Comment: In C# you need to use regex patterns to strip out the whitespace, before feeding in tab characters before indented tags.  This link is a start that will strip out the whitespace: http://dotnetperls.com/remove-whitespace